# Mouseover mouseleave and Click method on same element angular

Tags: angular, typescript, click, mouseover, mouseleave

I have a requirement where I have to show the preview of applicable font for a table on **mouseover**, set default font on **mouseleave** and apply the font on **click**. so I have called the methods on HTML element as below:

```
<a (click)="function('font')" (mouseover)="function('font')" (mouseout)="function('default')"><span  class="submenu-span">Regular 10</span></a>
```

and the function is as below :

```
function(font) {
    switch (font) {
        case 'xxx': {
            this.selectedFont.emit('size');
            break;
        }
        case 'yyy': {
            this.selectedFont.emit('size');
            break;
        }
        case 'default': {
            this.selectedFont.emit('size')
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but the function is not being called on click. every-time I click on element the mouseleave method overrides my click functionality.
What am I doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write separate methods for each event. I think that would easier for testing as well. If not, can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1):

`.stopImmediatePropagation` will solve your problem.

Follow this for more - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stop Immediate Propagation Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    div,
    p,
    a {
      padding: 15px 30px;
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid #000;
      https: //stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25917156#
      background: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div onclick="alert('You clicked: ' + this.tagName)">DIV
    <p onclick="alert('You clicked: ' + this.tagName)">P
      <a href="#" id="link">A</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function sayHi() {
      alert("Hi, there!");
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

    function sayHello() {
      alert("Hello World!");
    }

    // Attaching multiple event handlers to hyperlink
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.addEventListener("click", sayHi);
    link.addEventListener("click", sayHello);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create two classes:

1. Secondary class: This is a temporary class which you can add and remove on mouseover and mouseout. Also add the font to the class before adding it to the html view.
2. Main/Primary class: This is primary class and will be used on all your  or table. The click will modify this class and replace the font style.

Make sure that the secondary class rule overwrites the primary class.